# get Unique record among Duplicates Using mapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

### File.txt

```
123,abc,4,Mony,Wa
123,abc,4, ,War
234,xyz,5, ,update
234,xyz,5,Rheka,sild
179,ijo,6,all,allSingle
179,ijo,6,ball,ballTwo
```

**1) column1,column2,colum3 are primary Keys**

**2) column4,column5 are comparision Keys**

I have a file with duplicate records like above In this duplicate record i need to get only one record among duplicates based on sorting order.

**Expected Output:**

```
123,abc,4, ,War
234,xyz,5, ,update
179,ijo,6,all,allSingle
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code:

```
data = LOAD 'path/to/file' using PigStorage(',') AS (col1:chararray,col2:chararray,col3:chararray,col4:chararray,col5:chararray);
B = group data by (col1,col2,col3);
C = foreach B {
        sorted = order data by col4 desc;
        first    = limit sorted 1;
        generate group, flatten(first);
};
```

In the above code, you can change the `sorted` variable to choose the column you would like to consider for sorting and the type of sorting. Also, in case you require more than one record, you can change the `limit` to greater than 1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Questions isn't soo clear , but I understand this is what you need :

```
A = LOAD 'file.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (column1,column2,colum3,column4,column5);
B = GROUP A BY (column1,column2,colum3);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTERN(group) as (column1,column2,colum3);
DUMP C;
```

Or

```
A = LOAD 'file.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (column1,column2,colum3,column4,column5);
B = DISTINCT(FOREACH A GENERATE column1,column2,colum3);
DUMP B;
```